# AVAudioPlayer pausing issue

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, resume, performance

In my project, I have an AVAudioPlayer which plays a song. After I pause it, and hit   play again, it starts over instead of playing where I paused. Why is that happening?
Also, when I press play for the first time, it loads the song about 3-4 seconds. I thought I solved it by loading it on the other thread, but it still loads too slow (at least the view doesn't freeze anymore). How can I fix that? Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
  songIsCurrentlyPaused = NO;
  if(songIsCurrentlyPaused==YES){
    [self.background play];
  } else {
    playQueue = dispatch_queue_create("volume_change", NULL);
    dispatch_async(playQueue, ^{ NSString *filePath = 
      [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"some_song" ofType:@"mp3"];
      NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
      self.background = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
      self.background.delegate = self;
      [self.background setNumberOfLoops:1];
      [self.background setVolume:0.5];
      [self.background play]; });

      [trackNameLabel setText:@"Currently playing :\n some_song"];
      self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
  songIsCurrentlyPaused = YES;
  [self.background pause];
  [trackNameLabel setText:@"Currently playing : some_song (paused)"];
  [self.progressBar setProgress:self.background.currentTime/self.background.duration animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `songIsCurrentlyPaused` to `NO` at the beginning of `play:`

Try commenting it out:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
  //songIsCurrentlyPaused = NO;
  if(songIsCurrentlyPaused==YES){
    [self.background play];
  } else {
    playQueue = dispatch_queue_create("volume_change", NULL);
    dispatch_async(playQueue, ^{ NSString *filePath = 
      [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"some_song" ofType:@"mp3"];
      NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
      self.background = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
      self.background.delegate = self;
      [self.background setNumberOfLoops:1];
      [self.background setVolume:0.5];
      [self.background play]; });

      [trackNameLabel setText:@"Currently playing :\n some_song"];
      self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
  songIsCurrentlyPaused = YES;
  [self.background pause];
  [trackNameLabel setText:@"Currently playing : some_song (paused)"];
  [self.progressBar setProgress:self.background.currentTime/self.background.duration animated:YES];
}
```

If you want to get rid of that initial pause you're gonna have to completely reorganize your player setup. Initialize it before user can hit play button and also call:

```
[self.background prepareToPlay];
```

which will preload the song. Also move `songIsCurrentlyPaused = NO;` to some earlier place in code.

EDIT:

To get rid of initial delay you should move your initializing code to somewhere like `loadView` or `viweDidLoad`.

```
   //initialization code
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"some_song" ofType:@"mp3"];
   NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
   self.background = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
   self.background.delegate = self;
   [self.background setNumberOfLoops:1];
   [self.background setVolume:0.5];
   [self.background prepareToPlay];
```

Now this may cause a lag in UI display so you might wan't to consider preloading data
in background thread.

Your `IBAction` methods should then be modified:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender
{

   if (songIsCurrentlyPaused==YES) 
   { 
      [self.background play];
   }
   else
   {
      playQueue = dispatch_queue_create("volume_change", NULL);
      dispatch_async(playQueue, ^{
         [self.background setCurrentTime: 0.0];
         [self.background play];
      });

      [self.progressBar setProgress:0.0 animated:YES];
      [trackNameLabel setText:@"Currently playing :\n some_song"];
      self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

  }
  songIsCurrentlyPaused = NO;
}

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender
{
  songIsCurrentlyPaused = YES;
  [self.background pause];
  [trackNameLabel setText:@"Currently playing : some_song (paused)"];
  [self.progressBar setProgress:self.background.currentTime/self.background.duration animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Issue with the pausing solved! Thanks, much appreciated! But the loading is still slowish :(

Comment: @nemesis: i edited my answer. can't thest the code since i'm not at my mac at the moment. It should work but it may need some tweaking. The idea is to preload the music. If you can move the preloading on some background thread then there should be (almost) no delay.

Comment: Well, it works if you hit the play button after some time the view loads. Isn't there a way to completely remove the delay? Thanks!!

Comment: @nemesis: you _might_ speed it up a bit more if you s put `AVAudioPlayer` as a property of `AppDelegate` and start preloading it in background thread started in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. There will still be some delay - preloading takes it's time. Try to figure out a way to distract the user with some animation or something during this period.

Comment: I just did it by showing an alert that's suggesting him to take a look at the settings view :)) Big ups to you sir!!